# Add Speech recognition support for iOS 9 and older?

Tags: ios9, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

What is the best option to implement speech recognition in iOS 9? I have implemented SFSpeechRecognizer (Speech framework) for iOS 10+ but I also require support for iOS 9. Can somebody suggest a good approach for the same ?